# MS Sql Server Management Studio gives error on start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When i try to connect my sa account on sql server management studio it gives me this error:

*ps: the error message is turkish but you will see english version in 3rd image

[image]

Then i clicked on "Get Help For" thing as its shown above. It showed me this:

[image]

So i clicked to "Yes" button. Then it opened web page below:

*ps: error message is the same in first image but its english.

[image]

After that, i tried to start sql server process in services windows regarding 3rd image. But it gave me this error message:

It means "*Windows couldn't start SQL SERVER service on local computer. For more information see event logs. If this is not a Microsoft service, call provider and give this special error code: 3417*"

I wanted to look system event logs from C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs directory but there was 84 different .evtx files, I couldn't know what to do. How can i fix this?

*ps: I'm also not little bit confused about this problem's scope. I also thought to post this on superuser and/or stackoverflow but this place looked more convenient to me. So, if i'm mistaken please warn me.

[image]

**edit:**

I opened Event Log application in Control Panel\Administrative Tools according to Jon Siegel's suggestions and filtered all event logs from MSSQLSERVER source. There are 2 different error event.Below you can see event properties and link for event log online help documents.

**Error 1:** [image]

**Event Log Online Help Document for Error 1**: [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=SQL%20Server&ProdVer=10.0.5500.0&EvtID=9003&EvtSrc=MSSQLSERVER&FileVer=10.0.5500.0&)

**Error 2:** [image]

**Event Log Online Help Document for Error 2**: [Link 2](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=SQL%20Server&ProdVer=10.0.5500.0&EvtID=17187&EvtSrc=MSSQLSERVER&FileVer=10.0.5500.0&)

Comment: Look in the Windows Event Log and the SQL Server error log in the file system.

Comment: @JonSeigel Ok but which .evtx file should i look? there are 84 different .evtx file

Comment: Use the Event Log application in Control Panel\Administrative Tools.

Comment: Is it possible this was an evaluation edition that has expired?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i don't think so because i installed it long ago. Plus, i entered my key

Comment: @JonSeigel I didn't use this event log application. what should i do now?

Comment: Go into Windows Logs, then Application. In the list in the middle, look for messages from Source MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: @JonSeigel I edited my question, you can see screenshot at the end of it.
There are 82 events from "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)" But they're all information, their event id is 0. And when i right clied on them and chose Event Properties

Comment: Have you by chance compressed the drive containing SQL Server's system databases such as master.mdf?  This error indicates there is some issue with master.mdf

Comment: @MaxVernon My mdf files are not compressed. I updated my question, there are now 2 different errors i see on event log application, 1st one is about mdf files. You can see screenshot and a link for event log online help document.

Comment: @JonSeigel I updated my question, weird thing is now i see something on event log application that wasn't exist yesterday. There are 2 different error on event log application from the "MSSQLSERVER". I post screenshots and links for event log online help document

Answer (score 1):

Error code `3417` means that you have problems with your *`master`* database. More detailed information on this error can be found here: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337262%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The list of SQL server errors can be found in the MSDN by following address: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645601(v=sql.105).aspx. The solution is to recover the *`master`* database from the last backup. After this the SQL server will start and you will be able to connect.